# Is it possible to access a Silverlight DataGrid Column by name rather than by column index?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Does anyone know if it's possible to access a DataGrid column by using it's x:name (as defined in the xaml) from within the code behind ?

I know I can use the following code :

```
myDataGridList.Columns[0].Header = "Some Data";
```

..but I would prefer to use something like this if possible:

```
myDataGridList.Columns["ColumnName"].Header = "Some Data";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can extend ObservableCollection with some Linq or a foreach loop to do a linear search on the columns.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static DataGridColumn GetByName(this ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> col, string name)
    {
        return col.SingleOrDefault(p =>
            (string)p.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) == name
        );
    }
}
```

Then, you can call this instead of the Columns property:

```
myGrid.Columns.GetByName("theName");
```